# Cannot connect to DB2 Server From R Studio JDBC Driver

Tags: r, jdbc, db2

I have been trying to connect to my DB2 server for two days and have tried every post on here and have been unsuccessful to do so.

```
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)
library(DBI)

#Enter the values for you database connection
dsn_driver = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
dsn_database = "D0042T04"                   
dsn_hostname = "DB2"
dsn_port = "50000"
dsn_protocol = "TCPIP"
dsn_uid = "db2User"          
dsn_pwd = "secret!"          

jcc = JDBC("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver", "c:/development/R/db2jcc.jar");
path = "jdbc:db2://" +  dsn_hostname + ":" + dsn_port + "/" + dsn_database + sep=""

jdbc_path = paste("jdbc:db2://",  dsn_hostname, ":", dsn_port, "/", dsn_database, sep="");

conn = dbConnect(jcc, jdbc_path, user=dsn_uid, password=dsn_pwd)

query = "SELECT * FROM core.account FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY";
rs = dbSendQuery(conn, query);
df = fetch(rs, -1);

df

dbDisconnect(conn)
```

When I run the script I get the following

```
> query = "SELECT * FROM core.account FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;";
> rs = dbSendQuery(conn, query);
Error in dbSendQuery(conn, query) : could not find function "dbSendQuery"
```

Comment: If you debug (single step) through your code in rstudio, do you get any errors?  Have you tried with db2jcc4.jar (not db2jcc.jar) ? Verify that the path to that db2jcc4.jar is valid and that the file exists and is a recent version and that the Db2 driver is *correctly* installed. Also the line `path = "jdbc:db2://" +  dsn_hostname + ":" + dsn_port + "/" + dsn_database + sep=""` looks like it's suspect, though unused.  Also detail your base R version and your R-studio version if you need further help.

Comment: Also the value of your dsn_hostname looks suspect. If the Db2-server is running on the local machine, then use localhost or the real hostname.

Comment: I think it was the path the entire time. I was able to finally get it to connect using this simpler approach. https://www.r-bloggers.com/connecting-to-a-db2-database-from-r/

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to work just fine.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/connecting-to-a-db2-database-from-r/